# Update variable based on match in two tables

Tags: sas

I have 2 tables, lets name them `table1` and `table2`. Both of them have `credit_id`, `loan_id` and `Date` field. For some reason `credit_id` field needs to be updated with corresponding values from `table2`, linking data by `Date` and `loan_id` fields. To do so, I made a query like:

```
proc sql;
    UPDATE a
    SET a.credit_id = b.credit_id
    FROM table1 a, table2 b
    WHERE (a.Date = b.Date) AND (a.loan_id = b.loan_id);
quit;
```

According to googling, this query should work in many sql environments, but it seems that SAS is an exception here, because it seems that **from** part is ignored.

How to update needed field then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAS but have you tried a sub query to achieve your goal? Update Table1 Set Credit_ID = (SELECT Credit_ID From Table2 Where Table2.Loan_ID = Table1.Loan_ID)

Comment: What do you mean by sub query?

Comment: Please see my edited response above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the SQL, but you can do the same thing using a data step:

```
data table1;
  update table1 table2(keep = date loan_id credit_id);
  by date loan_id;
run;
```

This requires that:

- No two rows in the same table have the same date and loan_id, and
- Both tables are sorted/indexed by date and loan id

You need the `keep` on the transaction dataset in order to prevent it from updating/creating any other variables on the master dataset. There are also several other ways you could do this, e.g. using the modify or merge statements.

Comment: hi, what is the difference between update and modify?

Comment: I suggest you do some basic research via the SAS online docs and then ask a question here if you still don't understand.